# Is it possible to use wildcards #(single digit) and [](charlist) in Range.Find?

Tags: excel, vba

I can use * and ? in Range.Find, though get an error when I try to use # or [].

Is it possible to use them in Range.Find? If not, why? I'm curious about the reason behind...Thanks a lot!

Exp:

```
Debug.Print Cells.Find(What:="[1-100]", After:=Range("Q44"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Address
```

Comment: No, it is not possible.  The documentation says "To find cells that match more complicated patterns, use a For Each...Next statement with the Like operator".   I can only speculate to why you can not use a char list.  My guess is that they wanted to make Range.Find easy to use for the average non-programer.  After all supporting a char list means that you will need to escape characters.  Try explaining that to the average user.

Comment: @TinMan Thanks for your reply! It seems like a legit speculation.